# How to properly install react-scripts, as dependenc or as devDependency?

Tags: react-scripts

I see in different projects react-scripts installs as dependency or as devDependency and all works correctly in all projects.

But how to properly install it?

UPD:
npm i -D react-scripts
or
npm i react-scripts
?

In Visual Studio 2022, React template project has react-scripts in "dependencies", but ReactRedux template project has react-scripts in "devDependencies"

so, for react-scripts it doesn't matter how to install it, or exists any features?

Answer (score 0):

first you need to init npm: `npm init`

then install packages or script (as DevDependency): `npm i <package/s> --save-dev`

Answer (score 0):

as a shortcut of --save-dev you can use this :

```
npm i -D <some-package>
```